# Focus removed even after event returns false (cancelled event)

Tags: jquery

I have implemented hotkeys using [jquery.hotkeys](https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys/)

```
  $("textarea").bind("keydown", "tab", function() {
    alert("tab");
    return false;
  });
```

But I noticed that after the function returns, the focus is not in the textbox anymore. Its not in the next control too. I could do this.focus(), but I wonder why after returning false, the focus will be gone? also I am curious where did the focus go to

http://jsfiddle.net/Tu6vF/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the `return`, it's the `alert()` that loses focus (that's also the answer for the "where did it go?" part...the alert window it created).

[Here's your code without the alerts](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/Tu6vF/2/), never losing focus (at least, not because of your binds, clicking outside, etc works normally).